# $X_n$ independent variables if equations hold

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots ,X_n$ be random variables.

**Statement 1**

If for any $B_i \in \mathcal{B}^n, i=1,2,\dots,n$,

$$P\left( \overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcap}}X_i^{-1}\left(B_i \right) \right) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} P\left(X_i^{-1} \left(B_i \right) \right)$$

then $X_i$ are independent.

**Statement 2**

If we set $X=\left( X_1, X_2, \dots , X_n \right)$

and since
$$\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcap}}X_i^{-1}\left(B_i \right) = X^{-1}\left(B_1 \times B_2 \times \dots X_n \right)$$

then the equation in *Statement 1* is equivalent to

$$P_X \left( B_1 \times B_2 \times \dots \times B_n \right) = P_{X_1}(B_1) \times P_{X_2}(B_2) \times \dots \times P_{X_n}(B_n)$$

Does anyone have guidance on how to proceed proving these two statements?

**EDIT**

I want to show that if either *Statement 1* OR *Statement 2* is true for $B_i \in \mathcal{P}^n, i=1,2,...,n$, then $X_i$ are mutually independent.

$\mathcal{P}^n = \{ (a_1,b_1]\times(a_2,b_2]\times \dots \times (a_n,b_n]\} \cup \{ \emptyset \}$

**Attempt**

My idea is that if *Statement 1* is true for $B_i \in \mathcal{P}^n, i=1,2,...,n$ then, then by setting some $B_i = \mathbb{R}^n \in \mathcal{P}^n$ we get that for every subset of indices $I = \{i_1, \dots, i_k \} \subset \{1,2, \dots, n\}$  we have

$$P\left( \overset{k}{\underset{m=1}{\bigcap}}X_{i_m}^{-1}\left(B_{i_m} \right) \right) = \prod_{m=1}^{k} P\left(X_{i_m}^{-1} \left(B_{i_m} \right) \right)$$

for any $B_{i_m} \in \mathcal{P}^n$.

But the above does not imply that $X_i$ are mutually independent since we need it to be true for any $B_{i_m} \in \mathcal{B}^n$. How can I proceed from here?

If *Statement 2* is true I don't know how to proceed to prove independence.

Comment: Is not what you wrote the definition of independence? What is your definition?

Comment: @Shashi

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Let $X_i$ be a family of random variables, $i \in I$, $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. $X_i$ are independent iff for every finite set $\{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k\} \subset I$ and for every $B_1, B_2,\dots,B_k \in \mathcal{B}^n$, 

$$P\left( \overset{k}{\underset{m=1}{\bigcap}}X_{i_m}^{-1}\left(B_{i_m} \right) \right) = \prod_{m=1}^{k} P\left(X_{i_m}^{-1} \left(B_{i_m} \right) \right)$$

Comment: How the statement you want to prove any different than the definition?

Comment: @Shashi It is different because *Statement 1* states that this equation holds when using all $n$ of the variables $X_i$. Where the definition says it bust be true for every finite subset of indices for $X_i$. To make it more clear, as I understand it, It is true that 

$$ \overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcap}}X_i^{-1}\left(B_i \right) \subset \overset{k}{\underset{m=1}{ \bigcap}}X_{i_m}^{-1}\left(B_{i_m} \right)$$

$$\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcap}}X_i^{-1}\left(B_i \right)$$

What is true for a set $B \subset C$ is not necessarily true for $C$ as well.

Comment: @Shashi Disregard my last comment, I had some errors in my latex code and the limit for editing passed. Read my next comment.

Comment: @Shashi It is different because *Statement 1* states that this equation holds when using all $n$ of the variables $X_i$. Where the definition says it bust be true for every finite subset of indices for $X_i$. To make it more clear, as I understand it, It is true that 

$$ \overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcap}}X_i^{-1}\left(B_i \right) \subset \overset{k}{\underset{m=1}{ \bigcap}}X_{i_m}^{-1}\left(B_{i_m} \right),$$

$$\forall A = \{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k\} \subset I = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$$

What is true for a set $B \subset C$ is not necessarily true for $C$ as well.

Comment: Just take $B_i$ the whole target space for the indices $i$ you do not want to include. Is that it?

Comment: @Shashi This is my approach in my post though isn't it?

Comment: Yes, so you are done.

Comment: @Shashi I believe I am not since I arrive to the conclusion that the equation holds for any finite subset of indices and for any $B_{i_m} \in \mathcal{P}^n$. For the definition to be satisfied we need it to be true for any finite subset of indices and for any $B_{i_m} \in \mathcal{B}^n$.

Comment: try to use $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem

Comment: @Shashi I will look into it in, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X:(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})\to(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))$ be a random vector.

Based on the assumption of independence, we can proceed as follows:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}_{X}(B_{1}\times B_{2}\times\ldots\times B_{n}) & = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B_{1}\times B_{2}\times\ldots\times B_{n}))\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in B_{1}\times B_{2}\times\ldots\times B_{n}\right\})\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega \mid (X_{1}(\omega)\in B_{1})\wedge(X_{2}(\omega)\in B_{2})\wedge\ldots\wedge(X_{n}(\omega)\in B_{n})\}\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega \mid X_{1}(\omega)\in B_{1}\}\cap\ldots\cap\{\omega\in\Omega \mid X_{n}(\omega)\in B_{n}\})\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}\left(X^{-1}_{1}(B_{1})\cap X^{-1}_{2}(B_{2})\cap\ldots\cap X^{-1}_{n}(B_{n})\right)\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}_{1}(B_{1}))\times\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}_{2}(B_{2}))\times\ldots\times\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}_{n}(B_{n}))\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}_{X_{1}}(B_{1})\times\mathbb{P}_{X_{2}}(B_{2})\times\ldots\times\mathbb{P}_{X_{n}}(B_{n})
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response. My aim is to prove independence of the random variables $X_i$ starting with the assumption that either **Statement 1** or **Statement 2** is true, not the opposite.